# How to Set Color For CLRegion in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How to draw circle around the Monitoring Region in CLLocation manager. I want draw Circle around the region i have passed in CoreLocation without Maps.

```
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:point radius:100 identifier:@"Some Location"];
```

Comment: Please be clear while asking questions..

Answer (score 2):

CoreLocation doesn't have anything to do with drawing or UI. I don't understand what you mean when you say you want to draw a *"circle around the region I have passed in CoreLocation without maps"* - if you don't want to draw it on a map, what do you want to draw onto? If it is simply a plain UI view then you'll need to come up with an appropriate coordinate space, convert your `CLRegion` appropriately, and then use CoreGraphics to plot your circle - which should be fairly straightforward.